# dygraphs minification build error in a create-react-app project

Tags: create-react-app, dygraphs

I have added dygraphs to a large, existing project which was created with `create-react-app`. Everything runs well, I am importing dygraphs using the common syntax:

```
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';
```

However when I try to build my project with `npm run build` the ES6 bits of dygraphs cause the build to fail:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

        ..dev/node_modules/dygraphs/src/dygraph-utils.js:325

Read more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify
```

Following the link and looking at line 325 the minifier is tripping over the ES6 `=>` operator. Looking under node_modules/dygraphs, there are `src` and `src-es5` directories. I renamed `src` to `src-es6` and created a symlink:

```
src -> src-es5
```

Everything runs and builds just fine using this method but it doesnt seem like the best solution. The link provided suggests `ejecting` from the create-react-app rig and handling the build myself but that is not an option.

Any suggestions on a more proper way to handle this? Is there a specific way to `import Dygraph` from the es5 src directory instead?

Comment: If you change `module` from `index` to `index.es5` in `node_modules/dygraphs/package.json`, does that fix the issue? https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/6611837c5490f2f4b6d61967aa1ad658ed5f11d4/package.json#L6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the workaround as suggested by [@danvk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388951/danvk) works fine.

All you need to do is go to `package.json` at location - `node_modules/dygraphs/package.json` and change `module` value from `index` to `index.es5` and the build works just fine.

It's a bit of a hack, till the time this gets resolved. There is already a ticket opened for [this](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/926)

Comment: Yes this does work. @danvk repost as an answer and I'll re-check it, or I'll just check this post. Got sidetracked and forgot to get back to it...